# Singleton across compilation units: linking library vs linking objects

Tags: c++, singleton, static-linking

I apologize if the title is not fully self-explanatory. I'm trying to understand why my singleton factory pattern is not working properly, and I ran into a bizarre difference when using library vs linking single objects files.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bar.hpp"

int main (int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
  A::get().print();
  return 0;
}
```

bar.hpp

```
#ifndef BAR_HPP
#define BAR_HPP

#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  static A& get ()
  {
    static A a;
    return a;
  }
  bool set(const int i)
  {
    m_i = i;
    print();
    return true;
  }
  void print ()
  {
    std::cout << "print: " << m_i << "\n";
  }
private:

  int m_i;
  A () : m_i(0) {}
};
#endif // BAR_HPP
```

baz.hpp

```
#ifndef BAZ_HPP
#define BAZ_HPP

#include "bar.hpp"

namespace
{
static bool check = A::get().set(2);
}

#endif // BAZ_HPP
```

baz.cpp

```
#include "baz.hpp"
```

Now, I build my "project" in two ways:

Makefile:

```
all:
  g++ -std=c++11 -c baz.cpp
  g++ -std=c++11 -o test main.cpp baz.o
lib:
  g++ -std=c++11 -c baz.cpp
  ar rvs mylib.a baz.o
  g++ -std=c++11 -o test main.cpp mylib.a
```

Here are the outputs I get:

```
$ make all
$ ./test
print: 2
print: 2

$ make lib
$ ./test
print: 0
```

In the first case the call to `A::get().set(2)` in baz.hpp takes place, and the same instantiation of A is then used in the main function, which therefore prints `2`. In the second case, the call to `A::get().set(2)` in baz.hpp never takes place, and in the main function the value set by the constructor (that is, `0`) is printed.

So finally I can ask my question: why is the behavior different in the two cases? I would expect that either both print 0 once or print 2 twice. I always assumed that a library was just a compact way to ship object files, and that the behavior of linking mylib.a should be the same as that of linking baz.o directly. Why isn't that the case?

Edit: the reason, as explained by Richard, is that no symbols defined in baz.cpp are required in main.cpp, so baz.o is not extracted from the library and linked. This raises another question: is there a workaround to ensure that the instruction `A::get().set(2)` is executed? I would like to avoid making the singleton a global object, but I'm not sure it's possible. I would also like to avoid to include baz.hpp in the main, since there may be many `bazxyz.hpp` and that would require main.cpp to know in advance all of them, defying the whole purpose of the factory-like registration process...

Comment: nothing in main.cpp requires any symbol in baz.cpp, so the archived baz.o won't be linked into the executable

Comment: Does linking the object file force the linking instead? That makes sense I guess.

Comment: yes, explicitly linking the object file forces it into the executable.

Comment: Thanks. I added an edit with a follow up question. Do you see any workaround?

Comment: a singleton is a global object... which is why they are evil and should never be used.

Comment: Even as a static variable across different compilation units? I read a bunch of discussion and I started to get confused about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is to be a static library, then some module somewhere is going to have to address something in each implementation file of the objects that are going to register themselves with the factory.

A reasonable place for this would be in `bar.cpp` (which is a file you don't yet have). It would contain some or all of the implementation of `A` plus some means of calling the registration functions the widgets you're going to create.

Self-discovery only works if the object files are linked into the executable. This gives the c++ startup sequence a chance to know about and construct all objects with global linkage.

Comment: This is what I'm ending up doing. It annoys me that in bar.cpp I have to include all the headers for all the bazxyz.hpp, but it appears as there's no way around. In particular, it bothers me that when a new bazxyz.hpp is created, then the developer has to remember to add its include in the bar.cpp file.

Would this behavior change with a dynamic library? Not that it makes a difference for me, since I want to leave the choice to the user, but out of curiosity.

Comment: @bartgol you don't necessarily need to include the headers - just the external declaration of a function in the cpp file...

Comment: Well, it's still something that I need to add to bar.cpp everytime a new bazxyz.hpp is created. I guess I wanted to have my cake and eat it too...